# Question mark while trying to use BibTex

Tags: bibtex

This is my Latex code

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{amsart}
%DIF LATEXDIFF DIFFERENCE FILE
%DIF DEL RPI_R1_041.tex      Tue Sep  4 11:13:10 2018
%DIF ADD RPI_R1_041_RA.tex   Fri Sep 21 17:13:32 2018


\bibliographystyle{amsplain} 

\title{Concentração no ensino superior brasileiro: Maior qualidade vs. maior preço}
\author{Alessandro Rivello}
\thanks{Projeto de pesquisa para a matéria OI I}

\date{Initial draft: 19/03/2019. This version: \today}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \setcounter{footnote}{1}

    \section{Introdução}
    A presença de empresas privadas na oferta de vagas para o ensino superior brasileiro tem crescido ao longo do tempo. \cite{birds1998}

    \bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

and this is the output that I am getting
[image]

he following is my ref.bib file

```
%% LaTeX2e file `ref.bib'
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `Proj_OI1' on 2019/03/20.
%%
 @misc{birds1998,
  title   ={Sinopse EstatÃ­stica do Ensino Superior 2017},
  url     ={http://portal.inep.gov.br/basica-censo-escolar-sinopse-sinopse},
  organization={Instituto Nacional de Estudos e Pesquisas Educacionais AnÃ­sio Texeira},
  urlaccessdate={19 mar. 2019}
}
```

And this is the `.blg` file generated after compiling the Latex code

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: Proj_OI1.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Proj_OI1.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Proj_OI1.aux
You've used 1 entry,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            84 strings with 499 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
(There were 2 error messages)
```

I have being searching for a long time in the Latex stackexchange community and found a lot of related questions, but any of the solutions seems to work for me. What I am doing wrong?

## EDIT:

Thank you @daleif. Now I'm getting the correct citation in the text and the list of references is appearing as you can see bellow
[image]

But, as you can see the way the list of references are formatted is weird and I'm still getting some error messages while compiling as you can see from the `.blg` file

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: Proj_OI1.aux
The style file: amsplain.bst
Database file #1: ref.bib
Warning--to sort, need author or key in birds1998
You've used 1 entry,
            2213 wiz_defined-function locations,
            502 strings with 4033 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 196 in all, are:
= -- 11
> -- 1
< -- 0
+ -- 1
- -- 0
* -- 9
:= -- 25
add.period$ -- 1
call.type$ -- 1
change.case$ -- 3
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 2
duplicate$ -- 11
empty$ -- 27
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 41
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 1
missing$ -- 1
newline$ -- 13
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 10
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 2
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 8
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 5
swap$ -- 1
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 4
warning$ -- 1
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 2
write$ -- 14
(There was 1 warning)
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Copying my comment from under the removed answer: There is nothing particularly weird going on here. `amsplain` simply does not know about the fields `url` and `urlaccessdate` and does not print `organization` for `@misc` entries. That means you are left with the lone title of the entry. The style more or less knows the same fields as `plain` and `plain` has been around since before URLs were standardised. You can either choose a more modern style or put the URL and access date into `howpublished`.

Comment: thank you @moewe, I will look for some more modern style. Sorry for the confusion about how to enhance the question after daleif answer, still learning how to use the stackexchange properly.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently with `amsart` you **have** to place `\bibliographystyle` within the document body, not in the preamble. If placed in the preamble the `\bibstyle` is never written to the `aux` file.

So either place it in the body (I usually have it just above `\bibliography`) or use

```
\AtBeginDocument{
    \bibliographystyle{...}
 }
```